# Sending multipe arrays to a "server" (C#)

Tags: c#, tcpclient, tcplistener

Let's say i have a client, and a server. I want to send to the server two arrays:

1. Username (which is "a", for this example)
2. Password (which is "b", for this example)

I'm using this code to send to the server:

```
stream.Write (userd, 0, userd.GetLength);
stream.Write (passd, 0, passd.GetLength);
```

server side is :

The problem is that the output i get in the server side is "ab" both user and password, because i can't seperate between the password bytes and the user bytes, for it is all sent in one stream (i got it right?).

How can i do it properly? :O

Comment: How can i use fixed width?

Comment: My knowledge is yet very basic. I'm sorry i'f my questions sound stupid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is a little broad, but here goes. Basically, though, you have a number of options, and you just have to pick one and run with it. I mean, there are advantages and disadvantages to certain approaches, but you can work those out more easily than I can guess what you're doing this for.

You'll want to worry about security if you're doing something like this, but that's far out of the scope of your question, so I'll just assume you've got it covered.

These are just a few options off the top of my head.

**Use a Delimiter**

If you went with this, you'd have a single character that you know on the server and client, and can guarantee will never appear in the username (or you could get into escaping, if need be). If you chose a colon, for instance, you'd then send the server:

```
username:password
```

And the server could use `string.Split(':')` or equivalent to work out the arguments.

**Use Fixed Width**

Again, set up a contract, but here you have a certain number of characters that the username will take up no matter what, and will never exceed.

```
username     password
```

Then you can grab the `string.Substring(...)` to find the arguments.

**HTTP**

This is a big more complicated, but the `Authorization` header of an HTTP request uses a colon-delimiter like I originally mentioned. If you standardized to use HTTP for all requests, it might look something like this, with a bit of pseudocode.

```
GET /path HTTP/1.1
Authorization: BASIC [base64(username:password)]
```

**JSON / XML**

JSON and XML are formats for sending and storing data.

JSON would look something like this:

```
{ "username" : "thisIsTheUsername", "password" : "password01" }
```

XML would look something like this:

```xml
<creds>
    <username>thisIsTheUsername</username>
    <password>password01</password>
</creds>
```

Comment: @MrJack320 I hope that answers your question, or at least sets you on the right course.

Answer (score 0):

Can you serialize object to binary and send a stream on a server?
Then on a server deserialize binary stream to a object.